# I am reading file via parser in python but its not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

Here is a part of my parser. The problem is that it not reading and printing DeltaE and Intensity maybe someone could help ?

```
    if (line[1:24] == "Mulliken atomic charges" or
        line[1:22] == "Lowdin Atomic Charges"):
        if not hasattr(self, "atomcharges"):
            self.atomcharges = {}
        ones = inputfile.next()
        charges = []
        nline = inputfile.next()
        while not "Sum of" in nline:
            charges.append(float(nline.split()[2]))
            nline = inputfile.next()
        if "Mulliken" in line:
            self.atomcharges["mulliken"] = charges
        else:
            self.atomcharges["lowdin"] = charges

    if line[0:6] == 'DeltaE':
        while not "DeltaE" in nline:
            deltae = []
            intensity = []
            line=line.strip()
            #then we have a line like: DeltaE =    13.5423 | TDMI^2 = 0.6670E-01, Intensity =  6553.
            self.deltae = float(line.split('|')[0].strip().split('=')[1].strip())
            line = inputfile.next()
            self.intensity = float(line.split('|')[1].strip().split(',')[1].strip().split('=')[1].strip())
            line = inputfile.next()
            print deltae, ',', intensity
```

Part of output.log file (this output.log is very huge like 15mb)

```
   Initial state: <0|
   Final state: |1^1>
   DeltaE =    13.5423 | TDMI^2 = 0.6670E-01, Intensity =  6553.    
   ........................................
   Initial state: <0|
   Final state: |2^1>
   DeltaE =    17.9918 | TDMI^2 = 0.2693    , Intensity = 0.2668E+05
   ........................................
   Initial state: <0|
   Final state: |3^1>
   DeltaE =    22.4523 | TDMI^2 = 0.4740E-01, Intensity =  4644.    
   ........................................
```

I want to print DeltaE and Intensity after using parse method but nothing is working i can get other values but not DeltaE and Intensity:

```
 >>> mylogfile.parse()
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute charge: 0
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute mult: 1
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute natom: 82
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute atommasses[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute atomnos[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute vibsyms[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute vibfreqs[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute vibirs[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute vibdisps[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute temperature: 298.15
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute enthaply: -2225.475525
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute freeenergy: -2225.601048
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute grads[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute entropy: 0.000421006204931
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute atomcoords[]
[Gaussian BChla.out INFO] Creating attribute coreelectrons[]
<cclib.parser.data.ccData object at 0x02FA1890>
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: Where is the file you are trying to parse?  What result are you getting?  What result do you expect?

Comment: `line[0:11] == 'DeltaE'` looks incorrect to me, `DeltaE` is 6 characters but you are extracting 11 from the line to compare it against. Also `nline` is not modified inside the `while not "DeltaE" in nline` loop, so this loop will either short circuit or will execute forever. This is a fragile and error prone way to write a 'parser'.

Comment: I edited my comment, there's another obvious error. Also you create two lists `deltae = []
            intensity = []` and print them out, but never assign anything to them.

Comment: I would rewrite the parser in a more robust way, using for example regular expressions, this is a horrible mess.

Comment: maybe u can show me how you would rewrite it ?

Comment: I think you got confused because you copied the `charges` code, which reads in charges on multiple lines and creates a more complex data structure. I'll update my answer to show a way to fix your problem that involves less of a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the same approach, I think all you need to do is remove the extra code that you had mistakenly copied from the atomic charge parsing, this works:

```
    if line[0:6] == 'DeltaE':
        line=line.strip()
        #then we have a line like: DeltaE =    13.5423 | TDMI^2 = 0.6670E-01, Intensity =  6553.
        self.deltae = float(line.split('|')[0].strip().split('=')[1].strip())
        self.intensity = float(line.split('|')[1].strip().split(',')[1].strip().split('=')[1].strip())
        print(self.deltae, self.intensity)
```

Here's an example of a different approach for parsing that line - specifying a regular expression that matches the structure of the line. You need to add an `import re` somewhere such as at the top of the file:

```
        match = re.search(r"DeltaE =\s+(\S+).* Intensity =\s+(\S+)", line)
        if match is not None:
            self.deltae = float(match.group(1))
            self.intensity = float(match.group(2))
            print(self.deltae, self.intensity)
```

Here's a complete example that tests the code:

```
import re

class Parser:
    def parseline(self, line):
        match = re.search(r"DeltaE =\s+(\S+).* Intensity =\s+(\S+)", line)
        if match is not None:
            self.deltae = float(match.group(1))
            self.intensity = float(match.group(2))

p = Parser()
p.parseline("DeltaE =    17.9918 | TDMI^2 = 0.2693    , Intensity = 0.2668E+05")
print(p.deltae, p.intensity)
```

Output:

```
17.9918 26680.0
```

Comment: But this is whole new class and now i need somehow to call this in main parser ? Srr i am just newbie in python

Comment: I've created a class just so that I can test my example, and use `self` to have the same structure as your code. I don't know what your class that does the parsing is called. You should be able to replace all of your code after `if line[0:6] == 'DeltaE':` with the 4 lines begining with `match =`. You have to add `import re` somewhere too.

Comment: p = Parser() i also have to define my class name ye ?

Comment: You already have a class, and your code is in a class method. I created a class Parser just because I can't see that part of your code and I wanted to test my own.

Comment: Well then you did something wrong, such as didn't copy the first line of my code. That's why I post a complete working example.

Comment: Omg this python i hate , total confused, i donkt know which one is working now :((